# Determining reason for invalid_token in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-identity

Asp.Net Identity rejects tokens generated for password change and email confirmation with an error code 'invalid token'. How can we determine if this error was due to

- token that was not generated by the system OR
- expired token

I need to determine this in email confirmation scenario so that if the token was expired, I can regenerate automatically and send another token to the user.

Any ideas?

Thanks